# Using properties vs passing parameter in a method

Tags: cocoa-touch

Which is better of the two
Creating properties and passing it within methods in class or passing objects as parameters to a method?
I have a datamodel object instance returned by a handler class, which i want to pass it to two different methods, so what is the best approach, assing it to a property in the class and then use it into these two methods, or pass the instance as a parameter to the method?

Comment: it depends on the specifics of what you are doing, either could be a valid option.

Comment: I need to know the best practice fellows, so this question here.
As i said, getting an object from elsewhere and need to pass this object to two different classes again. So what would be the best practice? Getting the object and storing it as a property, and then use a parameterless method to update other classes, or create a method which will accept instance of this class as an object and use that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an object is only needed temporarily by a class to extract data from for example, then pass it as an method argument.

You should take a step back from the code details and have a more abstract look: If the object has no direct purpose, or does not meaningfully belong with the class, then passing it as a method argument is fine.  If the object could be seen as a part of the class (i.e. something the class needs all the time, or relies on a lot), then it might be an option to make it part of the class using a `property`.

Something else to consider is that setting a property, and then call a method that uses that property, separates the data from the operation.  I mean, this obscures what the method does, and on what data it works.  Of course this could be overcome by correct naming of those methods.  Again look at things at a bit more abstract level to find the most meaningful way (i.e. what is closest to the purpose of the class and what the methods are actually doing) of structuring things.

In other cases these object may belong to underlying/other classes, which means that your current class is only passing them on.  In those cases it's clear that you should literally pass them on with methods.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Will decide accordingly.